# HTML5 form validation for AJAX button submit

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have the following form. I like the new HTML5 form validation and I would prefer to keep it. However. I don't like the way that when the button is pressed it refreshes the page (form submit).

Instead I would prefer to use the button to trigger some AJAX to refresh page elements without refreshing the entire page. However, when I set `type="button"` what happens is that the HTML5 form validation ceases to trigger when the button is pressed.

**How can I use HTML5 form validation, while not triggering propagation of refreshing/submitting the page?**

Note that I'm not concerned with the AJAX elements of this problem, just the HTML5 validation issue.

```
echo "<form>";
echo "<td><input id=\"link_add_title\" type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"URL Title\"></td>";
echo "<td><input id=\"link_add_url\" type=\"url\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Your URL\"></td>";
echo "<td><input id=\"link_add_budget\" type=\"number\" step=\"any\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Budget\"></td>";
echo "<td><button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-success\"><i class=\"fa fa-check\"></i> Add</button></td>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: HTML5 validation doesn't reload the page in my browser ?

Comment: @adeneo - I'm using chrome. Don't know how other browsers have implemented the HTML5 standards but if it doesn't work on chrome I have a bit of a problem :)

Comment: Can you give us a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showing your form?

Comment: Well, try hitting submit in this fiddle, there's no page reload when the validation kicks in -> http://jsfiddle.net/Qv2c2/1/

Comment: See http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Comment: I surely don't get it, if you're trying to avoid the form submit when the form is actually valid, just use preventDefault in the form submit handler ?

Comment: Don't `echo`HTML in PHP, write it raw please - that's the main purpose of the language.

Comment: @adeneo how would I do that?

Comment: @moonwave99 I echo because I am generating it dynamically using php and also because it comes out minimised which reduces download time

Comment: Ok all sorted, thanks as always everyone!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Qv2c2/2/

Comment: @adeneo I take your point though I will post a jsfiddle in future when starting a question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This way you prevent actual submit, but HTML5 validation triggers:

```
$('form').submit(function(event){

  event.preventDefault();

});
```

As [Samveen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1353267/samveen) points out, this way should be preferred over listening to the `onclick` event of the `<button>`/`<input type="submit">` element, because the latter would prevent HTML5 validation in addition to normal form submit - [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ozrjbLwo/).

Comment: That works thank you! Obviously I will improve the selectors though so it doesn't apply to all forms :)

Comment: thanks for this answer!
i was going crazy over jquery Ajax html5 form validation not triggering when submitting form, but triggering after the form was submitted.

Comment: A small addendum: The usual paradigm is to do form submission on button click event: `$('button').click(function(evt){\*AJAX*\});` which needs to change to the above mentioned form submit event: `$('form').submit(function(event){\*AJAX*\});` in conjunction with altering the button type back to `type="submit"`

Comment: @Samveen: with `$(...).click()`, [you prevent HTML5 validation from happening](http://jsfiddle.net/ozrjbLwo/). So please listen to `submit` only : ))

Comment: @moonwave99: What you are saying is exactly what I discovered yesterday (the problem that lead me to this answer). All my form related code **incorrectly** listens to `$('button').click()`, this unfortunate paradigm being what I learned from searching on Google and SE(see [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20021021/1353267)). Thus my comment to point out the `gotcha` that got me.

Comment: @Samveen oh sorry, I understood the other way around! Thank you then ^^

Comment: @moonwave99, Would you the relevant parts of my comment as a note into your answer? It would make a great answer even better :) (something to the effect of **not** using `$('button').click()`, and using `$('form').submit(...)` instead?)

Comment: @Samveen sure, I just did!

Comment: I have problem with validation reset using html5 but it is not working using reset(). you can check using firefox... there is after submit border not cleared. 

`http://jsfiddle.net/KDkvE/`

i have trying to ask new question but its band dont know why

Answer (score 1):

With a submit button try..

```
html
<input type="submit" class="your-button-class" />

js
$(document).on('click','.your-button-class',function(){
 //your code

 return false;  //this will prevent the page refresh
});
```

Comment: This seems to stop propagation of the form but it also stops the HTML5 validation

Comment: I think this is a browser-specific solution :)