# How to validate Twitter Bootstrap forms?

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any good plugin to validate bootstrap forms? 
Or else, suggest links where I can find code validating them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 with jQuery Validation Plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754020/bootstrap-3-with-jquery-validation-plugin)

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of options out there:

- [jQuery validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)
- [Form validation for bootstrap](http://formvalidation.io/)
- [Validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/)

Related questions (with examples):

1. [Form Validation With Bootstrap (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296267/form-validation-with-bootstrap-jquery)
2. [How do I use Bootstrap 3 form validation when submit button is outside the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595416/how-do-i-use-bootstrap-3-form-validation-when-submit-button-is-outside-the-form)
3. [Bootstrap 3 with jQuery Validation Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754020/bootstrap-3-with-jquery-validation-plugin)

Comment: Why you give answer. You know this question is duplicate. You should flag this question

Comment: Could not find a question asking for different plugins to validate bootstrap, if you find any tell me and i will flag the question as duplicate and remove the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754020/bootstrap-3-with-jquery-validation-plugin

Comment: I don't think that someone asking for some help using jquery validation and bootstrap its the same as someone asking for different options to perform validation using bootstrap. You could flag it as duplicate if you want.

Comment: ok . i found this good question and I assume that this is duplicate of above question

Comment: Ok, you could flag it by yourself, i checked that question and is about styling error and warning fields, not about using a plugin to perform the validation.

Comment: does really need plugin. He need validation and maybe he thought plugin is the best resource for his purpose. So we can suggest him to use Jquery plugin because bootstrap still use jquery or he can follow [Mark error in form using Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361517/mark-error-in-form-using-bootstrap) this question. If OP could search on stackoverflow he did't need question. So I thnk that it is duplicate.

Comment: I know i am not going to change your opinion, but if you have time read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled "There could be hundreds of different, related, perfectly valid questions on the same topic. There is no One True Question." "It's rarely this straightforward, however -- usually there are two similar but not-quite-the-same questions, both of which have value for different reasons."

Comment: Thankyou @Partick LC . I got first two option from your answer and I'm now using jquery validator.

Comment: You are welcome, if you think the answer is valid you could accept it and upvote, have a good day!